# What is the purpose of lagering?

Tags: lager, lagering

I know all the cliche answers:  "it *rounds the beer out*", "it *cleans it up*", "it *takes away some of the harshness*".

I'm looking for a definitive answer of whats actually happening during extended cold storage.  Is it just clarity?  Are you dropping polyphenols/tannins that affect FLAVOR?  Couldn't this be achieved with some finings and a quick crash?  I've had some pretty darned clear beers that I've turned around in less than 2 weeks, grain to glass with some prepared gelatin, big yeast pitch, and careful manipulation of fermentation temp.

My only lager to date is Jamil's Oktoberfest that I primary'd @ 50* for 3 weeks, cold-pitched with about a gallon starter.  I have to be honest, I am a provisional BJCP judge, taking my tasting exam @ the end of the month, and consider myself to have a pretty good palette.  I couldn't really tell the difference between the sample of beer pulled @ 3 weeks, and the beer after it sat in a fridge for a month.

Listening to Jamil and John Palmer talking about it, it sounds like the purpose is largely to achieve clarity.  I also seem to remember Jamil saying something to the effect of "if you have a strong, healthy primary fermentation, you don't need to lager as much".

In many ways, it seems like decoction to me: an antequated process that is not really necessary anymore given upgrades in technology (in the case of decoction: advanced malting techniques; in the case of lagering: yeast selection/genetic modification, fermentation temp control, and refrigeration).

Or alternatively, maybe I just need more experience tasting pre-lagered lagers and brewing lagers! :^D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clarity and poly-phenol/tannins pretty much nails it.  Lager yeast do tend to be weaker flocculators than ale yeasts, so more time at cold temp helps clear things up.

I brewed up an all Munich malt beer with German Lager yeast.  It tasted so good after a 4 week primary that I kept drinking it during "lagering" and it was gone before the lager period was over.
In the same vein, I brewed an oktoberfest with the same yeast strain that wasn't great after primary, but most certainly was great after two months stored at 45F.

I think its style, recipe, water chemistry and palette dependent.

Comment: I think you are certainly correct about the recipe being a big factor. Seems like my all-Pils lagers turned around quickly, but my Vienna lagers with some roasted and crystal malts really needed several more weeks before the flavors all came together.

Comment: I feel like I have actually heard this before.  Lagers that have darker malts have, by nature, much more tannic/astringent flavors that cold-conditioning helps precipitate out (my understanding is that tannins are a very molecularly large polyphenol).  But that would be counterintuitive to your Okfest.  Ah the mysteries of brewing!